# $T$ is a generator of $\mathcal{T}$ iff. the ideal of $T$-ghost maps is contained in the Jacobson radical of $\mathcal{T}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

#### Definitions

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category with translation functor $\Sigma$.

- **Generator**: An object $T$ of $\mathcal{T}$ is a generator of $\mathcal{T}$ if $\mathcal{T}(\Sigma^n T,A)=0$ for all $n$ implies $A=0$.
- **$T$-ghost**: A map $f:A\to B$ in $\mathcal{T}$ is called $T$-ghost if the reduced map
  $$
  \textsf{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(\Sigma^n T,f) : \textsf{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(\Sigma^n T,A) \to \textsf{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(\Sigma^n T,B)
  $$
  is zero for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- **$T$-ghost ideal**: We denote by $\textsf{Gh}_{T}(A,B)$ the collection of all $T$-ghost maps between $A$ and $B$ and
  $$
  \textsf{Gh}_{T}(\mathcal{T}):=\bigcup_{A,B\in\mathcal{T}}\textsf{Gh}_T (A,B)
  $$
  Clearly $\textsf{Gh}_{T}(\mathcal{T})$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{T}$, called the $T$-ghost ideal of $\mathcal{T}$.
- **Jacobson radical**: For any objects $A, B\in \mathcal{T}$, the subgroup $\textsf{Rad}(A,B)$ of $\mathcal{T}(A,B)$ consists of all maps $f:A\to B$ such that $1_A - gf: A\to A$ is invertible, for any map $g: B\to A$. Now we define $\textsf{Rad}(\mathcal{T})$ as the collection of all subgroups $\textsf{Rad}(A,B)$:
  $$
  \textsf{Rad}(\mathcal{T})=\bigcup_{A,B\in\mathcal{T}}\textsf{Rad}(A,B)
  $$

---

Could you please help me with the Remark 2.9 in [this article](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esek/2008/ghosts.pdf)? Thank you very much!

> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category with translation functor $\Sigma$, let $T$ be an object of $\mathcal{T}$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $T$ is a generator of $\mathcal{T}$.
>
> (ii) The ideal of $T$-ghost maps is contained in the Jacobson radical $\textsf{Rad}(\mathcal{T})$ of $\mathcal{T}$.

*Proof*. (i) $\implies$ (ii). Let $f: A\to B$ be a $T$-ghost map. If $A=0$, then $gf = 0$ for all $g: B\to 0$ ($\color{red}{\text{right?}}$), so $1_A - gf = 1_A$ is invertible. If $A\ne 0$, then there is a morphism $l: \Sigma^n T \to A$ such that $f\circ l = 0$, hence $(1_A - gf)l = l$. Now how to show that $1_A - gf$ is invertible?

(ii) $\implies$ (i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) $\implies$ (ii): If $f \colon A \to B$ is a $T$-ghost and $g \colon B \to A$ is arbitrary, then $gf$ is a $T$-ghost and therefore $1_A - gf$ induces the identity map $\mathsf{Hom}(\Sigma^n T,A) \to \mathsf{Hom}(\Sigma^n T,A)$ for all $n$. If $C$ is the cone of $1_A -gf$ then the long exact sequence for Hom shows that $\mathsf{Hom}(\Sigma^n T, C)=0$ for all $n$, so $C=0$ since $T$ is a generator, so $1_A-gf$ is invertible.

(ii) $\implies$ (i): If $A$ is such that $\mathsf{Hom}(\Sigma^n T,A)=0$ for all $n$ then the identity map $1_A$ is $T$-ghost. But if the identity map is in the Jacobson radical then the zero map from $A$ to $A$ is invertible, which implies $A=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!